# Help with pulling data from different database servers in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working with SSRS 2008 and I need some help how I should approach this.

My requirement is that I need to create an SSRS report that I need to pull from 2 different databases in different servers in order to show the result. `Database1` has a unique id that I can use to query on `database2` which contain more details.

I am not sure if subreport would do the trick.

I do not have a linked server and is there a way I can pull the information from different database servers and join them?

Thanks.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411151/ssrs-muliple-data-sources and others, I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest way would probably be to use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx). This allows you to pull in data from another location and treat it as a table.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using  Look Up and Multi-Look Up  [functions](http://www.optimusbi.com/2012/07/25/building-ssrs-reports-multiple-data-sources/).

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't played a lot with 2008, so i'll tell you how i'd do it in 2005.

create 2 data sources, for for each server/database.  create two data sets.  drop a table on your report and set it to whatever your parent data set will be.  then drop a table inside the first table and set the data set to the child data set.  i don't have time to figure out the details from here, but you should be able to figure something out.